# "S&H" on a restaurant menu in Cyprus

Tags: abbreviations

I have seen "S&H" in restaurant menus in Cyprus. What does it mean? It seems related to a quantity of food in a serving.

```
 Grill             LARGE   S&H
--------------------------------
 Chicken fillet     8.70   5.90
 Chicken Kebab      8.90   6.10
```

Comment: Can't say I've ever seen it used on a menu. Whereabouts in the world are you seeing this?

Comment: It is in Cyprus

Comment: Where i've seen "S&H" on a invoice it would be "shipping and handling" but it's difficult to see that appiying to a restaurant unless they deliver.

Comment: I guess this belongs in the "Travel" SE. Perhaps the powers that be should migrate it there!

Comment: It's on-topic here, as it's about an abbreviation of an English phrase. It might be on-topic elsewhere too -- although it's not actually about the process of travel, so probably not Travel.SE -- but it was here first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a reference, which happens to be for a restaurant in Cyprus:

> The menu offers a "small and healthy" option for each dish, which we chose. I can't imagine how big the "regular" portion would be, as the "s&h" was very generous!
>
> [Tripadvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowUserReviews-g1916666-d8569599-r303961108-The_Bad_Cat-Kissonerga_Paphos_Paphos_District.html): "missindy" on The Bad Cat, Paphos

Comment: I've no doubt you're right that *in context*, this is what OP's example means. But it's not an *English Usage* in any meaningful sense. Without a glossary somewhere on the menu, **S&H** doesn't mean anything. Given that, I think this question is no more On Topic than a question about a random typo.

Comment: The OP asked what S&H stood for, and got the correct answer from Andrew. It's obviously a standard and well-known abbreviation in Cyprus. End of.